# How to use flink-s3-fs-hadoop in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink

I see the below info in flink's documentation - to copy the respective jar to plugins directory to use s3.
How can I do it if I deploy Flink using Kubernetes.

"To use flink-s3-fs-hadoop or flink-s3-fs-presto, copy the respective JAR file from the opt directory to the plugins directory of your Flink distribution before starting Flink, e.g.

mkdir ./plugins/s3-fs-presto
cp ./opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.9.0.jar ./plugins/s3-fs-presto/"

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing to k8s setup in [official docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html) you can simply re-create your image.

1. check out Docker file in [Github repository](https://github.com/docker-flink/docker-flink/blob/master/1.9/scala_2.11-debian/Dockerfile)
2. download `flink-s3-fs-presto-1.9.0.jar` to the same folder as your Docker file
3. add following right before `COPY docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
# install Flink S3 FS Presto  plugin
RUN mkdir ./plugins/s3-fs-presto
COPY ./flink-s3-fs-presto-1.9.1.jar ./plugins/s3-fs-presto/
```

4. build the image, tag it and push to Docker hub
5. In your Deployment yml file, change the image name to what you just created
6. You can then use s3://xxxxx in your config yml file (e.g. flink-configuration-configmap.yaml)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the build.sh script that's part of flink to build an application-specific docker image, it has a parameter (--job-artifacts) that allows you to specify a list of artifacts (JAR files) to include in the image. These jar files all end up in the lib directory. See https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-container/docker/build.sh.

You could extend on this to deal with the plugins correctly, or not worry about it for now (putting them in the lib directory is still supported).